# How to resolve SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module when running Vitest and TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typeorm, vitest

I found the following error while running Vitest tests that require a database connection:

[image: Error screenshot]

"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module."

This issue arose after I made some changes to my setup. Here's my new script for typeorm:

"migration:generate": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d ./src/infra/db/postgres/helpers/data-source.helper.ts migration:generate"

The migration file generated by this script is a TypeScript file named "1683049252085-CreateUsersTable.ts." When I changed the file extension from ".ts" to ".mjs", Vitest started running correctly.